# "Cannot move out of dereference `&`-pointer" with a vector

Tags: rust

I'm experimenting with Rust right now, and I'm getting really tripped up by all sorts of random compiler errors like this one:

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
    return list[idx];
           ^~~~~~~~~
```

The snippet in question is reproduced below. list is a word list, and the idea is to return a random word from list which is within a certain length (between minLength and maxLength). So, I generate a random uint and constrain it to the size of the list using a modulo. Then I want to check to see if that word is the right length, and if it is return it.

Obviously this isn't the most efficient way to do this, but I just wanted something easy that would fulfill the needs of the exercise.

```
fn get_a_word(list: Vec<String>, minLength: uint, maxLength: uint) -> String {
    loop {
        let idx = rand::random::<uint>() % list.len();
        if list[idx].len() > minLength && list[idx].len() < maxLength {
            return list[idx];
        }
    }
}
```

I've done some research into what this error message means, but everyone seems to say that this  comes up when you're dealing with `Option<T>` retvals, not attempting to get the value out of a collection.

This is probably a really simple question, but why on earth doesn't Rust just let you return a value from a collection/vector/array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list[idx]` is a shorthand for `*list.index(&idx)`. [`index()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) returns a borrowed pointer inside the value that is being indexed (here, the `Vec`). You cannot move a value (here, a `String`) by dereferencing a borrowed pointer; that would be like "stealing" a `String` from the `Vec`, which owns the string. A `String` owns an allocation on the heap; we can't have two `String` values that reference the same heap allocation, or they would both try to free it when they are dropped, which would lead to a double-free.

Since the function receives the `Vec` by value, it means the `Vec` is moved into the function, and therefore the function can do whatever we want with it, since it nows "owns" the `Vec` (the `Vec` will be destroyed when the function exits). For example, we can remove the `String` we want to return from the `Vec`, so that the `Vec` no longer has ownership of that `String`.

```
fn get_a_word(mut list: Vec<String>, minLength: uint, maxLength: uint) -> String {
    loop {
        let idx = rand::random::<uint>() % list.len();
        if list[idx].len() > minLength && list[idx].len() < maxLength {
            return list.remove(idx).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

If you didn't mean to have the `Vec` destroyed when `get_a_word` exits, then the function should receive a borrowed pointer to a `Vec` instead. If we do this, the function can simply return a string slice.

```
fn get_a_word(list: &Vec<String>, minLength: uint, maxLength: uint) -> &str {
    loop {
        let idx = rand::random::<uint>() % list.len();
        if list[idx].len() > minLength && list[idx].len() < maxLength {
            return list[idx].as_slice();
        }
    }
}
```

If you must absolutely return a `String`, then you can clone the value instead:

```
fn get_a_word(list: &Vec<String>, minLength: uint, maxLength: uint) -> String {
    loop {
        let idx = rand::random::<uint>() % list.len();
        if list[idx].len() > minLength && list[idx].len() < maxLength {
             return list[idx].clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Only one thing can own an object at a time, and what you’re trying to do there would break that invariant, as you would have the string you are returning in both the vector and in the return position. `list[idx]` expands more or less to `*list.index(idx)` for the method [`Index::index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) (in truth it’s a little more complex than that as whether it should be `Index::index` or `IndexMut::index_mut` is determined based on context, `&list[idx]` would be just a straight `list.index(idx)` and `list[idx].method()` for a `&self`-taking `method` would be `list.index(idx).method()`).

You have a few options; here are three:

- Remove the value from the list, returning it. The rest of the `Vec<String>` that you had will be dropped, and so all of the `String`s except for the right one will in the end be freed.

  `return list.swap_remove(idx).unwrap();` (compare [`swap_remove`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove) and [`remove`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove), the former is more efficient but alters the order which is perfectly OK in this case) in place of `return list[idx];` would do for this.
- Clone the string. This is less efficient but may be considered acceptable.

  `return list[idx].clone();` will do for this.
- Use slices and references through the whole thing: this is the most efficient way and typically the most idiomatic. It’s efficient as it doesn’t involve any allocations or deallocations or moving of large values.

  ```
  fn get_a_word(list: &[String], min_length: uint, max_length: uint) -> &str {
      loop {
          let idx = rand::random::<uint>() % list.len();
          if list[idx].len() > min_length && list[idx].len() < max_length {
              return list[idx].as_slice();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: How can you (quickly) tell that `list[idx]` expands to `*list.index[&idx]`? While I agree that it makes sense for it to do that, I cannot find a documentation for that. In fact, the function definition in the doc you posted, `fn index(&'a self, index: Idx) -> &'a Self::Output`, doesn't seem to demand that `index` be a reference.

Comment: @mSSM: it changed since then from taking the index by reference to by value. Now, `list[index]` is equivalent to `*list.index(index)` or `list.index(index)` or `list.index_mut(index)`, depending on how it is used. `&list[index]` is the canonical form, meaning `list.index(index)`, so it makes sense that just `list[index]` would be `*list.index(index)`. It’s also subject to autoreferencing rules, so `list[index].method_that_takes_self_by_ref()` is equivalent to `(&list[index]).method_that_takes_self_by_ref()`.